# A pointer "addr" in a struct was allocated memory but when I call it in another function, it can't work

Tags: c, pointers

At the beginning of the C file, I define two structures like this.

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[LEN];
    double price;
} book;

typedef struct
{
    void *addr;
    int num;
} Array;

Array book;
```

Later, I use `malloc(sizeof(void *)*len)` to allocate memory to the pointer `addr`. The void pointer points to a book structure which is also allocated memory in heap.

After doing this, when I call it in another function in this way:

```
void print_view_of_books(Array books)
{
   int j;
   int limit = books.num;
   for(j=0; j<limit; j++)
   {
      book * bk = (book *)books.addr[j]; 
      printf("Book title: %s\n", bk->name);
      printf("Book price: %lf\n", bk->price);
      puts("----------------------");
   }

}
```

My compiler says

> error: operand of type 'void' where arithmetic or pointer type is required. 1 error generated.

I find there's a problem with the expression `books.addr[j]` and if I substitute it simply with `books.addr`, it will work.

Can somebody instruct me how to fix the problem please?

Comment: What's the point to have and allocate array of void *pointers* ratther than `book`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem of operator precedence.

Changing `book * bk = (book *)books.addr[j];` to `book * bk = ((book *)books.addr)[j];` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> error: operand of type 'void' where arithmetic or pointer type is required. 1 error generated.

You are using pointer arithmetic on a void pointer which is not allowed ( addr[ j ] ).

First you have to cast the void pointer

```
((book *)(books.addr))
```

And then dereference it

```
((book *)(books.addr))[j]
```